# Placed Image in Illustrator is Blurry when exported as PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, image-quality, file-format

I am doing some work for a client designing stickers but their logo was originally created by someone else in Photoshop (I can't understand why a logo would ever be made in a raster format). So there is no vector version of their logo, only high-res JPEG and PNG versions.

In my design in illustrator I am having to place a JPEG of the logo into the designs, but when I export them as a PDF for print, the logo appears blurry and fuzzy. Despite being crisp when placed in Illustrator.

I have tried multiple PDF settings, with no difference. Is there anyway to fix this and get the logo to appear crisp in a PDF?

Again, if I export the design as a PNG or JPEG, it is perfect.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you please edit your quesion and add the following information. What is the size of the logo image file in pixels?  What physical size will it be reproduced at in the PDF?  Will the PDF be used for viewing on a screen, or will it be used for printing? What PDF Export settings are you using to export the Illustrator job?

Answer (score 2):

With everything done right, this should NOT happen. Most likely something wrong with one of the files. Or might just be an issue with your PDF viewer. Try looking at the same PDF using a different reader or a phone. Otherwise try linking that logo as PSD instead of JPG.